# Transaction Status

Tags: transactions, confirmations, byzantium

A very elementary question, how do I get a transaction status after firing the transaction? I mean suppose I do a sendTransaction where I transfer some amount of ether from 1 account to other, how can I check the status of the transaction using its hash?

Answer (score 67):

### Update Oct 21 2017

There are some changes with the Byzantium fork - `getTransactionReceipt(...).status` now returns 0 for a failed transaction and 1 for a successful transaction. EtherScan.io displays this status in the **TxReceipt Status:** field for transactions. See [How do I detect a failed transaction after the Byzantium fork as the REVERT opcode does not consume all gas?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28077/how-do-i-detect-a-failed-transaction-after-the-byzantium-fork-as-the-revert-opco) for further information.

---

## Summary

[`eth.getTransaction("{txhash}")`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransaction) and [`eth.getTransactionReceipt("{txhash}")`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt) will provide you with the details.

The `.blockNumber` field will be `null` until the transaction is included into a mined block.

The examples below show demonstrate some of the ways of detecting the status of a transaction.

Note that there could be an issue detecting whether a transaction has failed due to a thrown error, as the situation can be detected by checking whether `gas = gasUsed`. I've created the question [How can the transaction status from a thrown error be detected when gas can be exactly the same as the gasUsed for a successful transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6007/how-can-the-transaction-status-from-a-thrown-error-be-detected-when-gas-is-exact) to try to resolve this question.

And from the findings in the Q&A above, here's a short bit of code to determine the status of your transaction.

```
> var status = debug.traceTransaction("0x9ee86a200528de32a695f1e2dd0d94a3871fefc7e49c5fd24a4a37eab1b99f7a")
undefined
> status.structLogs[status.structLogs.length-1].error
"invalid jump destination (PUSH1) 2"
```

The return value above will be `""` if there are no errors, or `"Out of gas"` if you run out of gas.

---

## Details - Transaction Status

Following are some examples of using `eth.getTransaction(...)` and `eth.getTransactionReceipt(...)` to find out the transaction status.

### Pending Transaction, Not Mined Into Blockchain At Time Of Query

Here's the output when there are no pending transactions

```
// eth.getBlock("pending").transactions[0] = null
> eth.getTransaction(eth.getBlock("pending").transactions[0])
invalid or missing value for params[0]
    at web3.js:3119:20
    at web3.js:6023:15
    at web3.js:4995:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

And here's a pending transaction. `.blockNumber = null`.

```
> eth.getTransaction(eth.getBlock("pending").transactions[0])
{
  blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  hash: "0xdfa60d4e97c242c5222a11b485c051bbdeb133c99baccd34dc33ceae1dc0cd67",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 181930,
  to: "0x4ac944f4e8ab60f9481bcecd78a9915ed3eb98ba",
  transactionIndex: null,
  value: 1005685497455181600
}
```

---

### Transaction Mined Successfully, Transaction Status Good

This transaction was executed successfully. `gas(666666) < gasUsed(106824)`.

```
> eth.getTransaction(eth.getBlock("latest").transactions[1])
{
  blockHash: "0x425a4d04ac0185863266b0d1b000f579f9675a37c5c6df3bf3cf72e0bc9a94e7",
  blockNumber: 1701040,
  from: "0x81747eb1afd9e2670aa6883ed80973ffcb531e1f",
  gas: 666666,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  hash: "0x6ef5b459ed945fbabfc3a5ef34fb0087752002c319649ff44c3b2759d13a517d",
  input: "0xf04fd2f3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e0ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
  nonce: 16,
  to: "0x2cac6e4b11d6b58f6d3c1c9d5fe8faa89f60e5a2",
  transactionIndex: 1,
  value: 0
}

> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x6ef5b459ed945fbabfc3a5ef34fb0087752002c319649ff44c3b2759d13a517d")
{
  blockHash: "0x425a4d04ac0185863266b0d1b000f579f9675a37c5c6df3bf3cf72e0bc9a94e7",
  blockNumber: 1701040,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 127824,
  from: "0x81747eb1afd9e2670aa6883ed80973ffcb531e1f",
  gasUsed: 106824,
  logs: [{
      address: "0x2cac6e4b11d6b58f6d3c1c9d5fe8faa89f60e5a2",
      blockHash: "0x425a4d04ac0185863266b0d1b000f579f9675a37c5c6df3bf3cf72e0bc9a94e7",
      blockNumber: 1701040,
      data: "0x00000000000000000000000081747eb1afd9e2670aa6883ed80973ffcb531e1f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000025e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000047e364",
      logIndex: 0,
      topics: ["0xa8061486280834731cc1ef340255cc5d9880ad748d20cb766f43cb7562ec2c16"],
      transactionHash: "0x6ef5b459ed945fbabfc3a5ef34fb0087752002c319649ff44c3b2759d13a517d",
      transactionIndex: 1
  }, {
      address: "0x2cac6e4b11d6b58f6d3c1c9d5fe8faa89f60e5a2",
      blockHash: "0x425a4d04ac0185863266b0d1b000f579f9675a37c5c6df3bf3cf72e0bc9a94e7",
      blockNumber: 1701040,
      data: "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",
      logIndex: 1,
      topics: ["0x68a83b20dde5c87dee07cc8d46d46e2fda6f176227f8b1f20dcb93752557df0e"],
      transactionHash: "0x6ef5b459ed945fbabfc3a5ef34fb0087752002c319649ff44c3b2759d13a517d",
      transactionIndex: 1
  }, {
      address: "0x2cac6e4b11d6b58f6d3c1c9d5fe8faa89f60e5a2",
      blockHash: "0x425a4d04ac0185863266b0d1b000f579f9675a37c5c6df3bf3cf72e0bc9a94e7",
      blockNumber: 1701040,
      data: "0x00000000000000000000000081747eb1afd9e2670aa6883ed80973ffcb531e1f000000000000000000000000c3a48462221f4525dd2823853b0d04cf373fe42e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c7000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001840000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000047e558",
      logIndex: 2,
      topics: ["0x61a43b8785d66f3a53c7b8ab814b4c2e4ff15a1a6f8d24d08818e1f426e13906"],
      transactionHash: "0x6ef5b459ed945fbabfc3a5ef34fb0087752002c319649ff44c3b2759d13a517d",
      transactionIndex: 1
  }, {
      address: "0x2cac6e4b11d6b58f6d3c1c9d5fe8faa89f60e5a2",
      blockHash: "0x425a4d04ac0185863266b0d1b000f579f9675a37c5c6df3bf3cf72e0bc9a94e7",
      blockNumber: 1701040,
      data: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000075fbf48b22000",
      logIndex: 3,
      topics: ["0x8f22ef5ca888de3e246c690a13b066ad49cbf2768b0449441dd6f5bae826a1b1"],
      transactionHash: "0x6ef5b459ed945fbabfc3a5ef34fb0087752002c319649ff44c3b2759d13a517d",
      transactionIndex: 1
  }],
  root: "30353b57e937cfc71f0c97d5c98573be1eff440e3db62987bd9cd66b0f3030c4",
  to: "0x2cac6e4b11d6b58f6d3c1c9d5fe8faa89f60e5a2",
  transactionHash: "0x6ef5b459ed945fbabfc3a5ef34fb0087752002c319649ff44c3b2759d13a517d",
  transactionIndex: 1
}
```

---

### Transaction Mined Successfully, But Contract Execution Failed

Here is an [example](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x93f39d4213bc48d9e6adda181ddd468d18163ae894ffc3f1a81d34ea33629f84) of a transaction that was successfully mined into the blockchain, but the contract execution failed.

In this case `gas(50878) == gasUsed(50878)`.

This occurs because the Smart Contract code called by the transaction detected an error and threw an exception and this consumes ALL gas.

See [Why does a Solidity throw consume all gas?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2307/why-does-a-solidity-throw-consume-all-gas) for more information about the throwing of errors and gas usage.

And note that there could possibly be the case where a Smart Contract executes without any errors and consumes EXACTLY the same amount of gas as specified with the sent transaction details.

```
> eth.getTransaction("0x93f39d4213bc48d9e6adda181ddd468d18163ae894ffc3f1a81d34ea33629f84")
{
  blockHash: "0x43403d50e782e2e4f0e9c94e43ce417b2adaf0e0f9fbb4147c2b288fe3c9dc75",
  blockNumber: 1596065,
  from: "0x46fbf1e97365513bb5bdb894259877e026b7f27d",
  gas: 50878,
  gasPrice: 32210000000,
  hash: "0x93f39d4213bc48d9e6adda181ddd468d18163ae894ffc3f1a81d34ea33629f84",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 2,
  to: "0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  value: 211417498879620000000
}
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x93f39d4213bc48d9e6adda181ddd468d18163ae894ffc3f1a81d34ea33629f84")
{
  blockHash: "0x43403d50e782e2e4f0e9c94e43ce417b2adaf0e0f9fbb4147c2b288fe3c9dc75",
  blockNumber: 1596065,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 50878,
  from: "0x46fbf1e97365513bb5bdb894259877e026b7f27d",
  gasUsed: 50878,
  logs: [],
  root: "d6771cfbad8d1f2f7cf413a48e968654ec7626797d3ac0ee6cfac26bba09e352",
  to: "0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413",
  transactionHash: "0x93f39d4213bc48d9e6adda181ddd468d18163ae894ffc3f1a81d34ea33629f84",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

---

### Regular Transaction That Fails, Does Not Get Mined Into The Blockchain

I'm sending more ethers than is available in my account. The error is caught before the transaction is mined into the blockchain.

```
> eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(50000000, "ether")})
Insufficient funds for gas * price + value
    at web3.js:3119:20
    at web3.js:6023:15
    at web3.js:4995:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I'm sending to an invalid address. Again the error is caught before the transaction is mined into the blockchain.

```
> eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: "0x12345", value: web3.toWei(50, "ether")})
invalid address
    at web3.js:3887:15
    at web3.js:3716:22
    at web3.js:4939:28
    at web3.js:4938:12
    at web3.js:4964:18
    at web3.js:4989:23
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

---

### Transaction Mined Successfully, Transaction Status Good, gas=gasUsed

Here's an example where the `gas(21000) == gasUsed(21000)` but the transaction went through successfully.

I made this up as the gas required for a regular transaction is 21000 and I specified the `gas=21000` in the transaction details.

```
> eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(1.2345, "ether"), gas: 21000})
"0xc7c63b67747c0c825229ce3d36d226423adb8cab6bebe12b6d5001e0dc3f79b3"
> eth.getTransaction("0xc7c63b67747c0c825229ce3d36d226423adb8cab6bebe12b6d5001e0dc3f79b3")
{
  blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0xa7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2",
  gas: 21000,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  hash: "0xc7c63b67747c0c825229ce3d36d226423adb8cab6bebe12b6d5001e0dc3f79b3",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 55,
  to: "0x4d5bbe7fbc80933ffa90ece988a764e41ee6d018",
  transactionIndex: null,
  value: 1234500000000000000
}
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0xc7c63b67747c0c825229ce3d36d226423adb8cab6bebe12b6d5001e0dc3f79b3")
{
  blockHash: "0xf0af8236ceec7ad1839d67c9934ab062a8d95fa1f88b06139f97dbdfbd1cd842",
  blockNumber: 2234,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 21000,
  from: "0xa7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2",
  gasUsed: 21000,
  logs: [],
  root: "3280f47a0de1149ad5c5fda421faaf95f303da8a77e83c8ec6ac2b3d8ca27abc",
  to: "0x4d5bbe7fbc80933ffa90ece988a764e41ee6d018",
  transactionHash: "0xc7c63b67747c0c825229ce3d36d226423adb8cab6bebe12b6d5001e0dc3f79b3",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

Comment: So if a transaction has a blocknumber does it mean that it has not errored out?

Comment: It's a little bit more complicated. I'll try to answer this in a few hours when I get a larger slab of time.

Comment: Thanks for an elaborate reply. I looked at the other question (http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6007/how-can-the-transaction-status-from-a-thrown-error-be-detected-when-gas-is-exact ) which you had posted, so can we for sure looking at the last error field of the debug.traceTransaction state that the transaction has failed or not?

Comment: Should be. Test out my theory and report back if it does not work.

Comment: `gas(666666) < gasUsed(106824)` this is the contrary ? no ? 

The transaction is successfully if `gas(666666) > gasUsed(106824)`

Comment: Please add to your answer that client version should be 1.7.3 or above. Older clients still don't provide `status` field

Comment: @Max This does not seem to be true, I use Geth/v1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d/linux-amd64/go1.9 and I don't have the status property

Comment: @Andromelus are you on Ethereum mainnet?

Comment: @Max No, private network.

Comment: Do you control all nodes in the network?

Comment: @Andromelus, you will have to set `byzantiumBlock` in the genesis file for the status field to be active - see https://github.com/bokkypoobah/DeveryCrowdsale/blob/master/test/genesis.json#L4

Comment: So if gas <= gasUsed, then the transaction is successful? Please clarify. Thanks

Comment: @Russo See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28077/how-do-i-detect-a-failed-transaction-after-the-byzantium-fork-as-the-revert-opco