# how to find transaction success or failure programatically?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am using geth in linux and sending few transactions, and in out of 100 around 30 are getting errored.

1. How to find out Whether transactions went though or not with in geth cli.
2. How to find out what was the issue for rejecting transaction.

Thanks

Comment: Please share the error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As soon as you submit a transaction, you get a transaction hash. You can access the details of the transaction (such as the receipt) using that hash value. See the link below.
2. If the transaction was never mined, you are either not connected to any peers or you supplied a gas price that was too low. If the transaction was mined without success, the only reason I know is "out of gas", which is the only exception type in Solidity.

Once the transaction is mined (either with or without success), you can inspect the status in more detail as described [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6003/4938).

Comment: after the Byzantium fork there is a new OPCODE revert which is documented in this response https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/28078/682