# How can I tell from raw transaction data if it succeeded or failed?

Tags: web3js

I am getting into a bit of chain analysis and am using `web3.eth.getTransaction('0x8ab08c56c46ca42091ec44c7c9148fe5eb6e0355eeffb29acb5f6c3326139f9e')` to get the following transaction details:

```
{ blockHash: '0x2e5521db5cb9ea805cf50d979684969656fc3ecda22db58f16881af9d15da083',
  blockNumber: 48729,
  from: '0x3d0768da09ce77d25e2d998e6a7b6ed4b9116c2d',
  gas: 115510,
  gasPrice: { [String: '55866980572'] s: 1, e: 10, c: [ 55866980572 ] },
  hash: '0x8ab08c56c46ca42091ec44c7c9148fe5eb6e0355eeffb29acb5f6c3326139f9e',
  input: '0x60606040526040516102b43803806102b48339016040526060805160600190602001505b5b33600060006101000a81548173ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff021916908302179055505b806001600050908051906020019082805482825590600052602060002090601f01602090048101928215609e579182015b82811115609d5782518260005055916020019190600101906081565b5b50905060c5919060a9565b8082111560c1576000818150600090555060010160a9565b5090565b50505b506101dc806100d86000396000f30060606040526000357c01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009004806341c0e1b514610044578063cfae32171461005157610042565b005b61004f6004506100ca565b005b61005c60045061015e565b60405180806020018281038252838181518152602001915080519060200190808383829060006004602084601f0104600302600f01f150905090810190601f1680156100bc5780820380516001836020036101000a031916815260200191505b509250505060405180910390f35b600060009054906101000a900473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff163373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16141561015b57600060009054906101000a900473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16ff5b5b565b60206040519081016040528060008152602001506001600050805480601f016020809104026020016040519081016040528092919081815260200182805480156101cd57820191906000526020600020905b8154815290600101906020018083116101b057829003601f168201915b505050505090506101d9565b90560000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c48656c6c6f20576f726c64210000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  nonce: 8,
  to: null,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  value: { [String: '0'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] },
  v: '0x1b',
  r: '0x323e3ddd61c16d168fc73e1935e584b79e114a782fd424697abae985ee5d5906',
  s: '0x7f0b4c986006eebb87342b04e6b147778ca678393d520ced5f336c1ab081bab9' }
```

[Etherscan tells me that this transaction failed](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8ab08c56c46ca42091ec44c7c9148fe5eb6e0355eeffb29acb5f6c3326139f9e). How can I deduce that information from the above data?

UPDATE: Using `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0x8ab08c56c46ca42091ec44c7c9148fe5eb6e0355eeffb29acb5f6c3326139f9e')` does not yield much more info either:

```
{ blockHash: '0x2e5521db5cb9ea805cf50d979684969656fc3ecda22db58f16881af9d15da083',
  blockNumber: 48729,
  contractAddress: '0xf914866d52b690553c0aacece3b38cc8b463ea50',
  cumulativeGasUsed: 115510,
  from: '0x3d0768da09ce77d25e2d998e6a7b6ed4b9116c2d',
  gasUsed: 115510,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  root: '0xab42de6a98857259b73d8a1081ed068942cbff6e6b673a931ce97df3dc3350ee',
  to: null,
  transactionHash: '0x8ab08c56c46ca42091ec44c7c9148fe5eb6e0355eeffb29acb5f6c3326139f9e',
  transactionIndex: 0 }
```

Comment: web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt() should be used to get the transaction status. Not sure how to verify if the transaction failed or successful. Probably block number might be empty in case of failed transaction.

Comment: I thought so too, but web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt() is not much more helpful either (see above).

Comment: @Steve, cool are you 0x3D0768da09CE77d25e2d998E6a7b6eD4b9116c2D?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to check if gas sent == gas used.  If so, you can be reasonably certain the transaction aborted. Gas sent is in the `getTransaction` info: 115510; gas used is in the `getTransactionReceipt` info, also 115510.  See this [comprehensive write-up](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6002/transaction-status).

To access further info I think you'll need to enable transaction tracing on your node and use the node-specific tools to explore the trace logs. See [Parity's trace module](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-trace-module) for example. This is able to return success status of all transactions etc. I think [Geth's debug management API](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs) can do similar.

Comment: I am analysing 1000s of transactions and when sending Ether for example the gas sent == gas used (21000) so this would not hold then.

Comment: Understood - I've updated the answer with another suggestion.

Comment: Very cool. Starting geth like so `geth console --rpcapi eth,web3,admin` and using `debug.traceTransaction(txHash)` works.

Answer (score 0):

When using the web3 1.x, the returned result from `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash)` hast a status field which if true, the transaction was successful

```
 {
  blockHash: '0x1ddd1e460746115186874a9c1c1d232fc9f65bc60e4ffc740f36e85f629eb6f5',
  blockNumber: 16038776,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 10223841,
  effectiveGasPrice: 10608032517,
  from: '0x046b7aa8c3edb1022b9b9e0e59f4bfdb2f328191',
  gasUsed: 48513,
  logs: [
    {
      address: '0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48',
      blockHash: '0x1ddd1e460746115186874a9c1c1d232fc9f65bc60e4ffc740f36e85f629eb6f5',
      blockNumber: 16038776,
      data: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004c4b40',
      logIndex: 191,
      removed: false,
      topics: [Array],
      transactionHash: '0xcfd490f3e7a5d0916de22b7fd788fda2e72df6b75baa268f8028380c434684f3',
      transactionIndex: 126,
      id: 'log_b092b10b'
    }
  ],
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008100008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000001000000000000000800000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000',
  status: true,
  to: '0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48',
  transactionHash: '0xcfd490f3e7a5d0916de22b7fd788fda2e72df6b75baa268f8028380c434684f3',
  transactionIndex: 126,
  type: '0x0'
}
```