# geth commands to get the latest transactions per account or contract address

Tags: go-ethereum

Seen the response posted here at [https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6002/transaction-status#*=*](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6002/transaction-status#_=_)

Tried the following commands in the geth console, but getting the errors -

> eth.getTransaction(eth.getBlock("pending").transactions[0]) 
>   Error: invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type common.Hash at web3.js:3104:20 at web3.js:6191:15 at web3.js:5004:36 at :1:1
>
> getTransactionsByAccount("*") 
>   ReferenceError: 'getTransactionsByAccount' is not defined at :1:1