# Blocking an application untill metamask shows the transaction is complete

Tags: truffle, metamask, dapps

I’m creating a DAPP where I’m using Metamask for submitting the transaction. I have a requirement where when a user accepts/submits the transaction, a modal needs to appear on the page, blocking the application(so that the user can’t perform any other transaction) untill the transaction is complete/mined. I know about the modal part, but how can I block the application till the transaction is complete?

Comment: Check this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6002/transaction-status I hope it helps :)