# how do we know if transaction is rollback?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js

Transaction can be rollback because of various reasons, One of the reason can be, transaction run out of gas before it complete.

How do we know whether Transaction has rollback or not?

Is Ethereum provide any event or error which is use to find rollback transaction?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6002/transaction-status

Comment: since Byzantium there is now `status` field which means success or not

Answer (score 1):

I think taht what you are looking for are transaction receipts:
According to the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)

[image]

To have a concrete view you can take a look [to this transaction on etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3967f859c56c61f3365f6873ea001985e4e694952a9c22b68be731132c8e3e77).