# How do I find the transaction success from a receipt?

Tags: transactions, hash, receipts

Here is an example of a sucess:

```
{
  "hash": "0x17e0b789c7645eef46316d475419c02391181881f70eb0451bb13c29a2dd5133",
  "nonce": "0x14d",
  "blockHash": "0x7368ed3ff6d034cb38b8c521e272aa67a9fd50fe34ebbf0960fe47949d10a15d",
  "blockNumber": "0xd8e00e",
  "transactionIndex": "0x0",
  "from": "0x2096882843192129dd5b778531adefe4dfbeebed",
  "to": "0xbc948ec5aaa61a66b1641b1d403965701effacec",
  "value": "0x0",
  "gasPrice": "0x77359400",
  "gas": "0x4c4b40",
  "input": "0xea598cb00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002710",
  "publicKey": "0xbac5c6ab222cf37bbed7d34bd6d2ac87e5225730724dd0defb4724f9a8985e9eb6de8cb793f9c9c8f9277c53d7f5d6da814ed63570d3bc67bb78b070f18b78a0",
  "raw": "0xf88a82014d8477359400834c4b4094bc948ec5aaa61a66b1641b1d403965701effacec80a4ea598cb000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027101ca0a3e7242eeb8726f8b19643c3005af84e45fe4257f65e4f76e964a30aeede642aa057cf987e9afca2bc618dbe1e947075c4a0b9635a56e16f8af060a344ef3d096a",
  "r": "0xa3e7242eeb8726f8b19643c3005af84e45fe4257f65e4f76e964a30aeede642a",
  "s": "0x57cf987e9afca2bc618dbe1e947075c4a0b9635a56e16f8af060a344ef3d096a",
  "v": 28
}
```

Here is an example of a reverted transaction:

```
{
  "hash": "0xad3595a42afda6f3d340258448bf38b7aed995b1f3f830009b9e0aec708ba96a",
  "nonce": "0x106",
  "blockHash": "0xde32076d0028df0c2d800505ec91be55601ca4ae8d5d62a378d57447fe1129f1",
  "blockNumber": "0x16ceb65",
  "transactionIndex": "0x32",
  "from": "0xa9b8902b77004c2d9faa1bd5b044ea316cf8a1a3",
  "to": "0x78f2ae797f09915f51cc1cf64fd70b4f564290aa",
  "value": "0x38d7ea4c68000",
  "gasPrice": "0x2540be400",
  "gas": "0x5208",
  "input": "0x",
  "publicKey": "0x9149f6f823a88a351f1952e98f805b066899ec3a9f21c23b24f3e82914526cfbb41580a827db88c07cabedd9a690773706c66aab73cf9e3c255535a87ef6d0ad",
  "raw": "0xf86d8201068502540be4008252089478f2ae797f09915f51cc1cf64fd70b4f564290aa87038d7ea4c680008078a0f08254590fa90a7d570b239af144e1e3189574c6a18a99035809ea64d38fd201a04c31d1937694262b8e854626e6488ae7186b054aeb192cb2dd1cf3733e7f3094",
  "r": "0xf08254590fa90a7d570b239af144e1e3189574c6a18a99035809ea64d38fd201",
  "s": "0x4c31d1937694262b8e854626e6488ae7186b054aeb192cb2dd1cf3733e7f3094",
  "v": 120
}
```

How do I know which one was a success and which one was a failure? What is a general rule to apply to all transactions?

Comment: Those receipts are missing some fields status and gasUsed. They look more like transactions. In web3.js you have to call [`eth.getTransactionReceipt`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html#gettransaction).

Comment: I am using the web3j (Java) and can't use the .js  The call is "Transaction transaction = receipt.getReceiptByHash(txnHash, node);" the JSON I provided are the Transaction objects. I have to extract it either from the raw or r,s,v ...

Comment: Or just do whatever is answered here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6002/transaction-status
Thanks for a hint, didn't know that something was missing...

Comment: web3j has a [TransactionReceipt](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/web3j/protocol/core/methods/response/TransactionReceipt.java) class. If status is missing perhaps the blockchain doesn't include EIP 658 that introduces it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code

```
import Logic.Connection.HttpClient;
import org.web3j.protocol.Web3j;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.EthGetTransactionReceipt;
import org.web3j.protocol.http.HttpService;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CheckReceipt {

    public String checkTransaction(String txhash, String node) throws IOException {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.openClient();
        
        Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService(node, httpClient.getHttpClient()));
        EthGetTransactionReceipt transactionReceipt = web3j.ethGetTransactionReceipt(txhash).send();
        String status = "success";
        if (transactionReceipt.getResult() != null && !transactionReceipt.hasError()) {
            if (transactionReceipt.getTransactionReceipt().isPresent()) {
                String statusOfTx = transactionReceipt.getTransactionReceipt().get().getStatus();
//                System.out.printf("The status is %s%n", statusOfTx);
                if (!statusOfTx.equals("0x1")) {
//                    System.out.printf("Transaction reverted: %s%n", transactionReceipt.getTransactionReceipt().get().toString());
                    status = "reverted";
                }
            }
            else{
                status = "failed";
            }
        }
        else{
            status = "failed";
        }
        httpClient.closeClient();
        
        return status;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works, I will edit the code. Please accept the edit and I will accept the answer.

Comment: I think I'm not allowed to see and approve edits yet. when the big guys approve it, I will tell you to set it as an answer. :) @DamirOlejar

Comment: Already accepted :)  I hope the edit gets approved - Thanks!

Comment: For anyone wondering what Logic.Connection.HttpClient is, it is just a call to a new instance of OKHttp (sorry my mistake I haven't expanded it).