# How to know that transaction is transfer?

Tags: transactions, ether, bsc

When, I was watching transactions I saw tag transfer but I don't see this.

````
  hash: '0x22d44a7742aab325fb3e921d2d7c3f41f5d492a370e53bafe3f2b6c145670004',
  type: 0,
  accessList: null,
  blockHash: '0xf9b8c450305a63877d7eb9e19ef1dcef952dabcf08bf53adeab351980d18108f',
  blockNumber: 14448995,
  transactionIndex: 83,
  confirmations: 131654,
  from: '0x1a6352E6e2E0De831f32423A94Bb3114E2b3af85',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x012a05f200', _isBigNumber: true },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x5208', _isBigNumber: true },
  to: '0xB251c481D0d039A77E307B0ce03aaeE5E240FC56',
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x5af3107a4000', _isBigNumber: true },
  nonce: 666,
  data: '0x',
  r: '0xb26ee3a69d0acaa3c6217c80975371bb04d1be062729461d6296eaa05fbb5430',
  s: '0x31553e7bf291b43de47a0c18af57010cea2ba4e53aba458cbf1101dd495ef7db',
  v: 148,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 56,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
{
  to: '0xB251c481D0d039A77E307B0ce03aaeE5E240FC56',
  from: '0x1a6352E6e2E0De831f32423A94Bb3114E2b3af85',
  contractAddress: null,
  transactionIndex: 83,
  gasUsed: BigNumber { _hex: '0x5208', _isBigNumber: true },
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  blockHash: '0xf9b8c450305a63877d7eb9e19ef1dcef952dabcf08bf53adeab351980d18108f',
  transactionHash: '0x22d44a7742aab325fb3e921d2d7c3f41f5d492a370e53bafe3f2b6c145670004',
  logs: [],
  blockNumber: 14448995,
  confirmations: 131654,
  cumulativeGasUsed: BigNumber { _hex: '0xad2597', _isBigNumber: true },
  status: 1, 
  type: 0,
  byzantium: true
}```
Also,  I see status is one, but what does status mean is 0?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The transfer tag means that this transaction was made by triggering the receiver contract's transfer function which is the same as [web3's sendTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction). It executes transfers of a specified number of tokens to a specified address (see [this](https://www.investopedia.com/tech/why-crypto-users-need-know-about-erc20-token-standard/)).
- Status declares the transaction's success status: 1 for successful, 0 for failed transactions. Status of a transaction is provided by [web3's getTransactionReceipt](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt) (check [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6002/transaction-status/6003)).

Hope this helps.

p.s. Please declare the network of this data (I could not find the transaction hash on mainnet, rinkeby, ropsten or goerli).