# Would `throw` prevent this recursive attack?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, recursive

I am writing a basic contract to split ethereum evenly between two addresses.

Within my `withdraw()` function, I have the following code:

```
function withdraw() {
    uint256 amount = this.balance / 2;
    addressOne.transfer(amount);
    addressTwo.transfer(amount);
}
```

The problem is, having subsequent transfers like this enables recursive attacks. The owner of `addressOne` could call the function and overflow the stack right before the other half of the balance is sent to `addressTwo`.

Executed repeatedly, the owner of `addressOne` could drain the contract according to the series (assuming an even balance, i.e. no remainder):

[image]

My proposed solution then is the following:

```
if(!addressOne.send(amount)) throw;
if(!addressTwo.send(amount)) throw;
```

But would throwing like this prevent the same attack?

Comment: Why don't you write a test and find out? I've heard `truffle` is a pretty good tool to write and test contracts.

Comment: Checkout these links for more information: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6032/contract-throw-ether-sent-by-the-contract-also-reverted http://vessenes.com/ethereum-griefing-wallets-send-w-throw-considered-harmful/ https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/10/smart-contract-security/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with this contract.

1. Regardless of whether `throw` reverts the transactions, this wouldn't prevent a re-entrancy attack. If `addressOne` is the following contract:

   ```
   contract AddressOne {
      function() payable {
        OriginalContract.withdraw();

        // some case to stop recursion to prevent exhausting gas
      }
   }
   ```

   `addressOne` can drain the contract when `withdraw` is called. You can prevent this by doing one of two things: using a withdraw flow where each address withdraws their own share of the funds as they please or by putting a mutex over the contract global state. If you would like to do the former, check out my [splitter-contract](https://github.com/0xcaff/splitter-contract) for an example.
2. Anyone can call the `withdraw` function. I don't think this is intended.

Please correct me if I'm incorrect.

Comment: Valid point for #1, but for #2 It doesn't matter if someone else calls withdraw. They'd just be wasting gas, but I would still get my ether

Comment: There has to be a way to make subsequent send calls in a function and ensure they're both executed, I just haven't thought of it yet