# Difference between require and assert and the difference between revert and throw

Tags: solidity, contract-development, revert-opcode, exceptions, assert

I was looking at the [docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html) and I'm looking for clarification on the difference between `require` and `assert` and `throw` and `revert`.

> assert(bool condition): abort execution and revert state changes if
> condition is false (use for internal error)
>
> require(bool condition):
> abort execution and revert state changes if condition is false (use
> for malformed input)

Specifically with respect to `assert` and `require`, how do you draw the line between malformed input and internal error?

Comment: You may also want to check this excellent article on the topic: [Revert(), Assert(), and Require() in Solidity, and the New REVERT Opcode in the EVM](https://medium.com/blockchannel/the-use-of-revert-assert-and-require-in-solidity-and-the-new-revert-opcode-in-the-evm-1a3a7990e06e)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

**edit 2022-12-08:** As of Solidity 0.8.0 this answer is no longer accurate with respect to opcode and gas usage.

> Furthermore, internal errors like division by zero, assertion failure and others do not use the invalid opcode anymore, but use revert with a special error message, in order to not waste gas in such situations.

- [source](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15166/difference-between-require-and-assert-and-the-difference-between-revert-and-thro/24185#24185)

However the guidance around when to use which remains true, ie. you only really want to use `assert` for analysis, it's basically a `PANIC` now.

---

There are two aspects to consider when choosing between `assert()` and `require()`

1. Gas efficiency
2. Bytecode analysis

### 1. Gas efficiency

`assert(false)` compiles to `0xfe`, which is an invalid opcode, using up all remaining gas, and reverting all changes.

`require(false)` compiles to `0xfd` which is the `REVERT` opcode, meaning it will refund the remaining gas. The opcode can also return a value (useful for debugging), but I don't believe that is supported in Solidity as of this moment. (2017-11-21)

### 2. Bytecode analysis

From the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions) (emphasis mine)

> The require function should be used to ensure valid conditions, such as inputs, or contract state variables are met, or to validate return values from calls to external contracts. **If used properly, analysis tools can evaluate your contract to identify the conditions and function calls which will reach a failing assert. Properly functioning code should never reach a failing assert statement; if this happens there is a bug in your contract which you should fix.**

*The above excerpt is a reference to the still (as of 2017-11-21) experimental and undocumented `SMTChecker`.*

I use a few heuristics to help me decide which to use.

### Use `require()` to:

- Validate user inputs
- Validate the response from an external contract
  ie. use `require(external.send(amount))`
- Validate state conditions prior to executing state changing operations, for example in an `owned` contract situation
- Generally, you should use `require` more often,
- Generally, it will be used towards the beginning of a function.

### Use `assert()` to:

- check for overflow/underflow
- check invariants
- validate contract state *after* making changes
- avoid conditions which should never, ever be possible.
- Generally, you should use `assert` less often
- Generally, it will be use towards the end of your function.

Basically, `assert` is just there to prevent anything really bad from happening, but it shouldn't be possible for the condition to evaluate to false.

### Historical note:

The `require()` and `assert()` functions were added to Solidity prior to the Byzantium fork, in `v0.4.10`. Prior to Byzantium, they behaved identically, but already compiled to different opcodes. This meant that some contracts deployed before Byzantium [behaved differently](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17407/will-existing-contracts-behave-differently-when-revert-is-implemented-by-metropo) after the fork, the main difference being that began refunding unused gas.

Comment: But both `assert()` and `require()` rollback change written to the blockchain so that `balance[_to] =balance[_from] +_value` would be reverted if `assert()` or `require()` condition is triggered  isn’t it ? (I’m talking after last year's hardfork). Or does `assert()` keep change being made ?

Comment: Both rollback changes, which is indicated in the Gas Efficiency section.

Comment: I don't really understand the point of using assert anymore since I have the exact same behavior with require but I have the chance of refunding some gas, what's the purpose?

Comment: The difference is also semantic, ie. "this condition shouldn't even be reachable. Try compiling this code with a recent version of `solc`: https://gist.github.com/maurelian/02904ae729fb11213cde20ba05a202e6

It will warn you that it's possible for the second assert statement to be true for certain values.

Answer (score 25):

I'm using `require` for input validation as it's a little more efficient that if/throw.

```
function foo(uint amount) {
    require(amount < totalAmount);
    ...
}
```

Where as `assert` should be used more for runtime error catching:

```
function foo(uint amount) {
    ...
    __check = myAmount;
        myAmount -= amount;
    assert(myAmount < __check);
    ...
}
```

`revert` will revert changes and refund unused gas in a later version of Ethereum but ATM acts in the same way as throw.

Comment: Could I also just write assert(myAmount-amount<myAmount) and skip the __check variable? which one is better, why/why not?

Comment: Much safer not to have unnecessary duplication of logic in the state mutation and the `assert` argument.  To do so could lead to a debugging nightmare where the operations were chained for state but forgotten for the assert.

Comment: But both `assert()` and `require()` rollback change written to the blockchain so that `balance[_to] =balance[_from] +_value` would be reverted if `assert()` or `require()` condition is triggered  isn’t it ? (I’m talking after last year's hardfork). Or does `assert()` keep change being made ? But both `assert()` and `require()` rollback change written to the blockchain so that `balance[_to] =balance[_from] +_value` would be reverted if `assert()` or `require()` condition is triggered  isn’t it ? (I’m talking after last year's hardfork). Or does `assert()` keep change being made ?

Answer (score 19):

I think none of the answers is correct.

`assert` is reserved for conditions in which it is expected that static code analysis tools (maybe Solidity compiler in future versions) will be able to detect the error warning the developer at compile time.

`require` is reserved for error-conditions of incorrect input data to functions (when compared to expected/valid input data) that can not be detected until execution time. This correspond to function preconditions in programming language argot. The compiler is unable to help due to the infinite possibilities of input data.

`throw` is deprecated in favor of revert.

`revert` is reserved for error-conditions that affect business-logic. For example someone sends a vote when the voting is already closed.

`require` and `revert` are mostly similar respect to the internal EVM implementation, but developers will appreciate the distinction.

Comment: Very updated answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

`Assert` is suitable for checking conditions which are not meant to occur but do.

`Require` is suitable for checking for unwanted conditions which can occur.

Answer (score 1):

Solidity has an [SMTChecker](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/smtchecker.html) which makes using `assert` very cool because it can **prove** that your invariants are true:

> Solidity implements a formal verification approach based on [SMT (Satisfiability Modulo Theories)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories) and
> [Horn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability) solving.
> The SMTChecker module automatically tries to prove that the code
> satisfies the specification given by `require` and `assert`
> statements. That is, it considers `require` statements as
> assumptions and tries to prove that the conditions inside `assert`
> statements are always true.  If an assertion failure is found, a
> counterexample may be given to the user showing how the assertion can
> be violated. If no warning is given by the SMTChecker for a property,
> it means that the property is safe.

#### You should use `assert` to help you find invariants which have been violated.

You use `assert` to help you catch when the impossible happens.

The [SMTChecker Tutorial](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/smtchecker.html#tutorial) provides a good example of [`assert`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/smtchecker.html#assert) that is too lengthy to include here: highly recommend to read it.

If the SMTChecker gets you excited to start using `assert`, that's a very good thing.  But remember they are for *invariants*, as the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/control-structures.html?highlight=assert#panic-via-assert-and-error-via-require) mention:

> Assert should only be used to test for internal errors, and to check
> invariants. Properly functioning code should never create a Panic, not
> even on invalid external input. If this happens, then there is a bug
> in your contract which you should fix. Language analysis tools can
> evaluate your contract to identify the conditions and function calls
> which will cause a Panic.