# Will existing contracts behave differently when REVERT is implemented by Metropolis?

Tags: solidity, metropolis, revert-opcode

Solidity v0.4.10 introduced the `revert()` and `require()` functions, along with support for the [`REVERT` opcode](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/d4a57d81ba7f2a9b5db57397d36f1a17adb4b142/libevmasm/Instruction.h#L180). As far as I can tell, this means that any contract compiled using `^0.4.10` will express different behavior on `throw` after metropolis.

**Background:**

According to the [Solidity Exceptions documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.10/control-structures.html#exceptions):

> user-provided exception is generated in the following situations:
>
> 1. Calling throw.
> 2. Calling require with an argument that evaluates to false.

and

> Internally, Solidity performs a revert operation (instruction `0xfd`) when a user-provided exception is thrown.

**Conclusion:**

So, it seems that recently compiled/deployed contracts will include the `0xfd` opcode, which on homestead is just an `INVALID` operation, but will become `REVERT` after metropolis.

**Question:**

Is my conclusion correct?

Are there any cases where the the changed behavior could be problematic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, per [this conversation](https://medium.com/@pirapira/even-before-metropolis-the-opcode-throws-a3a590387211).

> All undefined instructions behave the same way as INVALID. And yes, the behavior of `0xfd` changes at Metropolis, but before or after Metropolis, `0xfd` always throws. The difference is whether some output is made available for the caller...  and, also that the remainder of gas is refunded.