# Will revert() refund all gas of the transaction or just the remaining gas?

Tags: solidity, gas, security, evm, revert-opcode

According to [the docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions) `revert()` will not consume any gas:

> Note that assert-style exceptions consume all gas available to the call, while revert-style exceptions will not consume any gas starting from the Metropolis release.

But i frequently read that `revert()` will refund **unused** gas, e.g. in [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/15167/7111).

I'm thinking refunding ALL gas will open gates for DOS-attacks, so I'm assuming only unused gas will be refunded. But I would like confirmation :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Just the remaining gas.**

`revert` will keep unused gas: meaning the caller will have the unused gas to perform further computations.  [refund](/questions/tagged/refund) is different and you're correct that if `revert` gave back gas to the caller, that would allow DoS attacks (a caller could loop many times, then `revert`, loop, and `revert` infinitely).

Comment: So can we say that usage of revert() will be preferred over throw, as it saves the caller some gas? E.g. in cases the caller makes a mistake and provides wrong parameters, causing the contract to raise an error.

Comment: @TripleSpeeder Yes, `throw` is being deprecated.

Comment: @eth what s the gas cost of revert itself?

Comment: @user2284570 according to this answer require(which essentially wraps revert) does though very little, about 23 gas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48085107/10261711