# Change value if function parameter is not zero

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation

I have this function.

How do I change only the parameters that aren't zero when calling the function? This is what I did

```
function changeParameters(uint newAnte, uint8 newNumberOfPlayers, uint newWinnerPart) {
    if (msg.sender == owner) {
         if (newAnte != 0) {
            ante = newAnte;
         }
         if (newNumberOfPlayers != 0) {
            required_number_players = newNumberOfPlayers;
         }
         if (newWinnerPart != 0) {
            winner_part = newWinnerPart;
        }
        }
}
```

I'm certain there has to be a more efficient way

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `require` for input validation, it is more efficient than using `if`.

Please check this answer for more details.

[Difference between require and assert and the difference between revert and throw](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15166/difference-between-require-and-assert-and-the-difference-between-revert-and-thro/15167#15167)

Answer (score 1):

I added a constant None as suggested by another answer that was deleted. That solved my issue:

```
uint80 constant None = uint80(0); //null constant


function changeParameters(uint newAnte, uint8 newNumberOfPlayers, uint newWinnerPercentage) {
    // Only the creator can alter this
    if (msg.sender == owner) {
     if (newAnte != None) {
        ante = newAnte;
    }
    if (newNumberOfPlayers != None) {
        required_number_players = newNumberOfPlayers;
    }
    if (newWinnerPercentage != None) {
        winner_percentage = newWinnerPercentage;
    }
}
```