# How to access error statement written with require?

Tags: solidity, web3js

From solidity 0.4.22, we can use a message with revert and require keywords to get an exact error message.  [ref](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.22)

> You can specify error reason strings for revert and require (support
>   by tooling is still pending).

A sample contract illustrating this :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;
contract TestExceptionHandling{
    uint public a ;
    constructor(uint _a) public{
        a= _a;
    }
    function increaseA(uint b) public{
        require(b > a, 'new value must be greater than a');
        if (b > 50){
            revert('Very large value');
        }
        a = b;
    }
}
```

This code compiler without nay error. This is really awesome, thanks to devs for this.

But **how can I capture this error in my DAPP using web3 or so?**

Comment: I think that `support by tooling is still pending` pretty much answers your question.

Comment: [Same question is discussed here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40993/returning-an-error-code-with-revert) Hope this will help!