# Contract deployed in private blockchain not returning output

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, private-blockchain

This is my smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
contract Greet
{
  string message;
  constructor() public{
        message="I'm ready!";
    }
function setgreetings(string _message)public
{
    message=_message;
}
function getgreetings()public view returns(string){
       return message;
 }
}
```

I deployed my Greetings smart contract to my private network.

```
  var myABI = [{"...."}]
  var myCont = eth.contract(myABI)
  var myCode = "0x..."
  var txDeploy = {from: 'account_address', data: myCode, gas:210000}
```

// unlock the account to send the transaction

```
   var app = myCont.new(txDeploy)
```

// mined the block
// got the address of the deployed contract
Now using remix to call getgreetings function. It should return "I'm ready".
But it is blank:
[image]

Contract works fine when I use JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded JS EVM in Remix is synchronous in nature and will return immediately with the return value. Real node software is asynchronous and you will synchronously only get the transaction hash. Later, when the transaction is included, you'll get the transaction receipt. However, the receipt itself has only a status field (0: failed, 1: success). There is no field for the return value.

See "[why are return values only True or False](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/59942/why-are-return-values-only-true-or-false/59952#59952)" how to navigate around this.

Comment: I am deploying my contract in my private network using remix IDE and now its working fine. But I deploy it from geth console it's not working.

Comment: If you’re sending a transaction from geth’s console, the only thing you get in return is the tx receipt. And it has no field for a return value as you’re expecting.