# How do I fix this compile error: "throw" is deprecated in favour of "revert()", "require()" and "assert()"?

Tags: solidity, mist

I've just downloaded **Mist 0.9.0** and I tried to compile a new contract but it does not let me do it with this error:

```
"throw" is deprecated in favour of "revert()", "require()" and "assert()".
      throw;
      ^---^
```

In this code caused by the modifier onlyOwner:

```
/*
 * Ownable
 *
 * Base contract with an owner.
 * Provides onlyOwner modifier, which prevents function from running if it is called by anyone other than the owner.
 */
contract Ownable {
  address public owner;

  function Ownable() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  modifier onlyOwner() {
    if (msg.sender != owner) {
      throw;
    }
    _;
  }

  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
    if (newOwner != address(0)) {
      owner = newOwner;
    }
  }

}
```

I'm not a Solidity developer, **is it correct this edit?**

```
  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require (msg.sender != owner);
    _;
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between require and assert and the difference between revert and throw](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15166/difference-between-require-and-assert-and-the-difference-between-revert-and-thro)

Comment: The equivalent code is `require(msg.sender == owner);`.