# Why using assert, since it would consume all gas

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-verification, require, assert

Since `assert` would consume all gas and `require` would return all gas, is there any reason to use `assert` not `require`? Using `require` to refund gas seems always a better choice than consuming them?

I saw some explanation in [Difference between require and assert and the difference between revert and throw](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15166/difference-between-require-and-assert-and-the-difference-between-revert-and-thro)
but I still don't get it: what is the benefit of choosing a command that consumes all gas?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `assert` (over `require`) to indicate your intention to source code analyzers such as oyente. While `require` is good to validate input, it can sometimes be false because the user did something innappropriate. `assert`, on the other hand, is meant to indicate something that should never be `false` under any circumstances. Knowing this, a source code analyzer can possibly detect a logical error in the system by discovering any situation in which the `assert` might not be `true.`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to punish the naughty users who supply bad arguments to your functions, you should use up all their gas :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good article: https://codeforgeek.com/assert-vs-require-in-solidity/

Philosophically, they are intended to mean two very different things. `require` is "user should have done this before calling the function", whereas `assert` means "something fundamentally is wrong".

Pragmatically, it depends on what your intention is. If the goal is to ensure the least impact on the user, then `require` is preferred only because it returns the gas. However, if your intention is security/auditability/maintainability/clarity of intention, then there are situations where you'd prefer one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

#### You should use `assert` to help you find invariants which have been violated.

You use `assert` to help you catch when the impossible happens.

Solidity also has an [SMTChecker](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/smtchecker.html) which can  **prove** that your invariants are true:

> Solidity implements a formal verification approach based on [SMT (Satisfiability Modulo Theories)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories) and
> [Horn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability) solving.
> The SMTChecker module automatically tries to prove that the code
> satisfies the specification given by `require` and `assert`
> statements. That is, it considers `require` statements as
> assumptions and tries to prove that the conditions inside `assert`
> statements are always true.  If an assertion failure is found, a
> counterexample may be given to the user showing how the assertion can
> be violated. If no warning is given by the SMTChecker for a property,
> it means that the property is safe.

The [SMTChecker Tutorial](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/smtchecker.html#tutorial) provides a good example of [`assert`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/smtchecker.html#assert) that is too lengthy to include here: highly recommend to read it.

#### Since `assert` should never be false, you do not have to worry about consuming all the user's gas.

If the SMTChecker gets you excited to start using `assert`, that's a very good thing.  But remember they are for *invariants*, as the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/control-structures.html?highlight=assert#panic-via-assert-and-error-via-require) mention:

> Assert should only be used to test for internal errors, and to check
> invariants. Properly functioning code should never create a Panic, not
> even on invalid external input. If this happens, then there is a bug
> in your contract which you should fix. Language analysis tools can
> evaluate your contract to identify the conditions and function calls
> which will cause a Panic.