# What's the point of 'assert'? Can't i just use 'require' all the time?

Tags: solidity

I read [this stackexchange post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15166/difference-between-require-and-assert-and-the-difference-between-revert-and-thro) and understood the difference between 'assert' and 'require'.

But it got me thinking, **what even is the point of 'assert'?** I mean it has same the behaviour as 'require' except ***gas won't get refunded***.

Can't we **just use 'require' all the time**, since it has the added possibility of gas being refunded?

If this isn't the case, then can somebody please give an example of a scenario where we should use 'assert' and explain why we need to specifically use it instead of 'require'.

Thanks!

Comment: You should check out this thread https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27812/why-using-assert-since-it-would-consume-all-gas?rq=1
The answer is just what you are looking for!