# Is there anyway a smart contract creator can put a limit on the gasPrice(gwei) for a transaction?

Tags: gas, gas-price, tokens

I am looking at the possibility of creating a custom token on the Ethereum network & wanted to know if there is a way if i can put an limit on the gasPrice in order to prevent the so called "gas wars" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require(tx.gasprice < 5 * 1000000000);
```

From [Block and transaction properties. Solidity Docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=Gasprice#ether-units)

Comment: what happens to the state of the transaction if i do this ?

Comment: "require(false) compiles to 0xfd which is the REVERT opcode, meaning it will refund the remaining gas." [Source](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/15166/9938).

Comment: The transaction will be reverted to the initial state.

Comment: its safe to say that require(false) is equal to if(false) revert(); ?

Comment: @SujalMandal yes. Solidity performs a revert operation (instruction 0xfd) in both scenarios.