# What should happen if I push a value into array and the function fail afterwards?

Tags: contract-development, arrays, exceptions

What should happen when I modify an array, afterwards in the same execution the function fails?

**Should I expect the pushed value to be presented or does it get deleted?**

for example:

```
contract MyToken is ERC721Token("My Token", "MYTKN"), Ownable {

    struct TokenInfo {
       // ...
    }

    TokenInfo[] public tokens;

    // ...

    function mint(string userId) public payable {

        uint256 tokenId = tokens.push(newToken) - 1;
        string tokenUri = concat(BASE_URI, tokenId);

        // >>>>>>>>> Maybe function fails here <<<<<<<<

        // ...

        _mint(msg.sender, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, tokenUri);


        // >>>>>>>>> Maybe function fails here <<<<<<<<    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the transaction fails,and causes to run `REVERT` opcode,  all the modifications will be reverted as they never happened, except the gas cost to execute upto that will be reduced from your account.

For e.g. `Out of gas error` or `require` or `revert` statement in Solidity will revert the changes.

Solidity documentation [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions) provides a comprehensive guide on error handling and the answers to [Why does a Solidity throw consume all gas?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2307/16301) provide more details.

Comment: "except the gas cost to execute upto that will be reduced from your account" this is only if the failure calls the REVERT opcode, as in a `require` or `revert` statement in Solidity. If the failure is because of pretty much anything else, it'll eat all available gas.

Comment: @flygoing Thanks for pointing out, when it says a failure I only had Out of gas error in my mind. I edited the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Out of gas error will revert all changes as well