# Why is there gas infinity here?

Tags: solidity, remix, gas-limit

I'm starting with Solidity and Smart Contracts, and the static analysis in Remix is complaining about gas infinity for the function bet:

```
contract Forecast {
    
    struct Bet {
        address payable owner;
        uint price;
    }   

    // the bets
    mapping(uint => Bet) bets;
    
    // number of bets
    uint public betCount;

    //bet value
    uint public betValue; 

    // Amount accumulated
    uint public accPot;

    /// Not enough funds to bet
    error NotEnoughFunds();

    constructor (uint _betValue) {
        betValue = _betValue;
    }

    function bet(uint price) public payable {
            
        if (betValue > msg.value)
            revert NotEnoughFunds();
        
        bets[betCount++] = Bet(payable(msg.sender), price);
        accPot += msg.value;
    } 
}
```

Test:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
import "remix_tests.sol"; // this import is automatically injected by Remix.
import "remix_accounts.sol";
import "../contracts/Forecast.sol";

// File name has to end with '_test.sol', this file can contain more than one testSuite contracts
contract testSuite {

    Forecast forecast;
    
    function beforeAll() public {
        forecast = new Forecast(42);
    }

    /// #sender: account-1
    /// #value: 42
    function testBet() public payable {
        Assert.equal(forecast.betValue(), 42, "Bet value should be 42");
        Assert.equal(forecast.accPot(), 0, "Accumulated pot should start at 0");
        Assert.equal(forecast.betCount(), 0, "Bet count should start at 0");
        Assert.equal(msg.value, 42, "Msg value should be 42");
        
        forecast.bet(42);
        
        Assert.equal(forecast.betCount(), 1, "Bet count should be 1");
        Assert.equal(forecast.accPot(), 42, "Accumulated pot should be 42");
    }
}
```

In fact, when I run a test I get the error:

> ✘ Test bet
> Error Message:
> "Transaction has been reverted by the EVM: { "transactionHash": "0x2bd817dc53af5b2bf6cf5bba53207bf462283a8a229b5d66b3e5eae1f28fcc65", "transactionIndex": 0, "blockHash": "0xd19b57b71cc4948048baba6363ba841a56ddeedeaa65f1b4caffd7c5bd5e2e3f", "blockNumber": 47, "gasUsed": 5000000, "cumulativeGasUsed": 5000000, "status": false, "to": "0x3c725134d74D5c45B4E4ABd2e5e2a109b5541288", "events": {} }"

All documentation I read says too much gas might be spent on unbound loops and that kind of stuff, but here is just 2 assignment, so I really don't understand.

**EDITED:**
I modified the code to make a minimum test case.
The error I see during the test indeed comes from the `revert NotEnoughFunds();` line (which I don't know why because the test has the correct values, but that's a different story). However, as per @xavier59 comment and the link he provided, `revert` reverts the transaction and doesn't consume all the gas.

Comment: Maybe you have a bug or something throwing in your contract : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2548/56242

Comment: The code `revert SweepstakeAlreadyEnded();` doesn't compile. What are `SweepstakeAlreadyEnded()` and `NotEnoughFunds()`?