# Smart Contract GridLock / Stuck Thread

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, evm

Since Smart Contracts can call multiple contracts, is there a chance that smart contracts enter a gridlock situation?

Comment: Deadlocks are discussed here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4564/can-you-execute-a-contract-twice-in-one-block

Answer (score 1):

No.

Transactions a well-ordered and execute serially. Contracts can call other contracts, which passes flow control to the other contract.

Although they can be logically entangled (`parent do child.method()`, and `child do parent.method()`) there is no wait loop so those methods either return or fail.

The block `gasLimit` is the outer bulwark against the "halting problem". A transaction that does not complete "on budget" is deemed failed.

Have a look over here for more discussion of concurrency: [What is the order and concurrency behavior of multiple calls to a contract in a single transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/what-is-the-order-and-concurrency-behavior-of-multiple-calls-to-a-contract-in-a)

Hope it helps.